# Why is this ternary statement evaluated as NULL?

Tags: c#, linq, ternary-operator

The first ternary statement in the following code is returning "null".  myID is coming back as null.  However, if the ternary statement worked properly, and a.someID is null, then myID should come back as -1.  myID is a nullable int field.  Do you know why I'm not getting back a -1?  Thanks.

```
public List<myView> GetRecords()
{
    myEntities entities = new myEntities();

    var myValue = (from a in entities.myEntitiesA
                   join b in entities.myEntitiesB on a.myID equals b.myID into myEntitesC
                   from c in myEntitesC.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new myView
                   {
                       myID = a.someID == null ? -1 : a.someID,
                       myName = a.myName,
                       myAlternateID = c.myID == null ? -1 : c.myID,
                       myAlternateName = c.myName == null ? "" : c.myName,
                   }).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b.myName).ToList();

    return (myValue);
}
```

EDIT - I've gotten rid of the DefaultIfEmpty() for the sake of testing, but my results are the same.

Comment: also - you might want to dispose your `myEntities`.

Comment: How are you determining that `myID` is `null`?

Comment: @Razvan - someID is a nullable int as well.

Comment: @JaredPar - I can see that someID is null in the underlying database record.

Comment: @WEFX that would indicate though that `null` was evetnually being written to the record not that it was being returned as `null` from the above query.  Have you checked the result of `GetRecords` in the running program to see if `myID` is `null`?

Comment: @WEFX Did you confirm myAlternateID was null immediately before returning out of the method you provided? It seems myAlternateID is getting set to null outside the scope of the provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all of the other answers seem valid, none of them work for me.  Since I was calling this GetRecords() method from a JsonResult controller method, I ended up performing additional logic on my JsonResult, checking for NULLs a second time.  This, of course, is a redundant check so it's not ideal, but it DOES work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use the null coallessing operator which is `??`

```
// y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1.
        int y = x ?? -1;
```

from [?? Operator Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: Valid point, but since it is equivalent to what he's alerady doing this isn't an answer to the stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  from c in myEntitesC.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new myView
  {
    ...
    myAlternateID = c.myID == null ? -1 : c.myID,
```

What if c is null?

```
    myAlternateID = (c == null || c.myID == null) ? -1 : c.myID,
```

---

Linq is a way to declare queries using a common syntax against many different implementations.  Your particular query implementation may not be LinqToObjects (as implemented in static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`).  To get the best answer, it is appropriate to specify what system is executing your query.

Comment: If c is null you'd get an exception, not a null assignment

Comment: @rotan - exception is not guaranteed. If the query is translated by LinqToSql, no exception would occur. Also - why write DefaultIfEmpty if the only thing it can do for you is to generate an exception?

Comment: I've gotten rid of DefaultIFEmpthy(), but the same problem remains.

Comment: @WEFX: You haven't answered what LINQ is talking to, although your class names seem to indicate you're using Linq to Entities.

Comment: @comecme - Yes, I'm using Linq to Entities in an MVC3 / EF4 web project.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the DefaultIfEmpty() routine is being triggered so your ternary operator is not being executed, but rather a new myView is being created.

Comment: I've gotten rid of DefaultIFEmpthy(), but the same problem remains.